# What is the difference between braces and commas when used to separate arms of a match expression?

Tags: rust, expression

I just started learning Rust and there are some things that confuse me.

I read Chapter 2 of the book, Programming a Guessing Game and some parts of the code are making me wonder what is right or not.

Example:
Here's a loop I asked about in [another question](/q/62102532/3650362):

```rust
 loop {
    ...

    match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
        Ordering::Less => println!("Too small!"),
        Ordering::Greater => println!("Too big!"),
        Ordering::Equal => {
            println!("You win!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I realized I could write this instead:

```rust
 match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
    Ordering::Less => {
        println!("Too low!") // without semicolon ;
    } // without comma ,
    Ordering::Greater => {
        println!("Too high!")
    }
    Ordering::Equal => {
        println!("You win!!!");
        break;
    }
 }
```

I find it confusing, I don't know if it's good or wrong, if it could cause future breaking changes ...
Can anyone help me understand?

Comment: There's a little article on [block expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/block-expr.html) and to what they evaluate

Comment: @AlexLarionov thanks, I'm going to read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma at the end of match arm is optional if braces are used. The rust parser/tokenizer can unambiguously parse the match arms with or without comma. [Look here:](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/match-expr.html)  comma is optional.

Anything ending with semicolon is a statement which doesn't return any value (expect return <>; statement).

In the first case,

```
Ordering::Less => println!("Too small!"),

// Returns a unit value
```

In the second case with braces, the last line without the semicolon would be returned. In this case, it is a [unit value.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.unit.html)

See this example:

```
   let flag = false; 

   let result = match flag {
        false => {
            println!("in false arm");
            100
        },
        true => {
            println!("In true arm");
            200
        }
   };
   println!("result = {}", result);
```

This prints the following:

```
in false arm
result = 100
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f4a531293d9fc82459da0c3fbcf0e93d

Comment: It does not explain why I can separate arms with blocks of code without using commas.

Comment: The comma at the end of match arm is optional if braces are used. The rust parser/tokenizer can unambiguously parse the match arms with or without comma.

Look here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/match-expr.html
comma is optional

Comment: This should not be a comment; it is vital information that needs to be in the answer. As it's currently written this proposed answer doesn't address the question that was asked.

Comment: Ok added to answer

Comment: @JCorriveau Note that if you run `rustfmt` on your code, as you should, it will delete extraneous commas used with blocks.

Comment: @trentcl yes, but it also leave some that seems useless `match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
        Ordering::Less => println!("Too small!"),
        Ordering::Greater => println!("Too big!"),
        Ordering::Equal => println!("You win!"), // <===
    }`

Comment: @JCorriveau It's not important for the parser, but it does minimize changed lines of code should you ever add another arm to the `match`, so it's not completely useless.